# $.when.apply not working when one of the promises in the array of promise is deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array which stores promises returned from different functions . I have used

```
_.each(someDiffArray,function(element){ 
       var promise = renderSomething(); 
       promiseArray.push(promise);
  }
```

where renderSomething returns deferred promise sometimes.

```
$.when.apply($, promiseArray).done(function() {
    //doSomething
});
```

But when one or more of the promises in `promiseArray` is deferred and it is resolved and other promises have yet to be done or resolved control is going inside the callback function of `$.when.apply`.

I dont know why this is happening , can somebody help? Is it because of the behavior of deferred or is there some other problem?

Comment: Please create a demo that replicates this behavior

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you reproduce your problem in a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: This behaviour occurs if any of the requests in `promiseArray` fail - have you checked the status codes of the requests?

Comment: Rory is right, you should change your callbacks to .then and .catch or .error for better practice.

Comment: @Rory, indeed, but in that case `done()` wouldn't run (`fail()` or `always()` would), so I still cannot explain the questioner's observed behavior that way.

Comment: _.each(someDiffArray,function(element){                                                 var promise = renderSomething();   promiseArray.push(promise);} where renderSomething returns deferred promise sometimes. This is before $.when.apply line.

Answer (score -1):

You can use promise library like BlueBird. Here is an example of what you are trying to achieve. Following are few promise functions and on their resolution I will do something:

```
function a(){
    return Promise.resolve("a");
}
function b(){
    return Promise.resolve("b");
}
function c(){
    return Promise.resolve("c");
}
function d(){
    return Promise.resolve("d");
}
function e(){
    return Promise.resolve("e");
}
function f(){
    return Promise.resolve("f");
}
```

Now

```
Promise.all([
    a(),
    b(),
    c(),
    d(),
    e(),
    f()
]).then(function(response){
    console.log(response);
}).catch(function(er){
    console.error("Err: ", er);
})
```

`then()` will be called when all the promise resolved successfully otherwise `catch()` will be called if any promise is rejected. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6wk1uzqu/